# Change owner of file without being root

Tags: linux, file-permissions, chmod

I suggest that I have a log file with 666 permission and its owner is alice. So user 'bob' can change its owner by this:

```
cp log log.temp; rm log; mv log.temp log
```

So how can I fix this risk?

Comment: Put its ownership as 600?

Comment: 'bob' can do that only if he has write permissions for the directory containing the file.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrey says above, bob can only do what you say if he has rights over the directory which contains the file. Just change the dir permissions to xx5 if you want bob to access but being unable to create new files.

from [Understading UNIX permissions](http://www.zzee.com/solutions/unix-permissions.shtml)

Access permissions for files and folders mean different things from the user standpoint.

**For Files**

- **Read:**  If the file contents can be read
- **Write:** If user or process can write to the file (change its contents)
- **Execute:** If the file can be executed

**For Directories**

- **Read:** If the directory listing can be obtained
- **Write:** If user or process can change directory contents somehow: create new or delete existing files in the directory or rename files.
- **Execute:** If user or process can access the directory, that is, go to it (make it to be the current working directory)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the OP had a good reason for alice and bob to have write permissions to the log dir the alternate answer is.

```
chmod og+t directorypath
```

The problem is not that the user can read the log file, or even that they can create new files in the same dir, it's that they can move and delete the existing log file.

`+t` restricts move and delete of files in a dir to only the owner of the file (root aside).

This is how `/tmp`  dir works.